# Is it me or just everyone is having laptop problem while using "Colors" in flutter in android studio?

Tags: android, flutter

Recently, I was using flutter in Android studio and I was using :
"background: Colors.purple". While I was using Colors the suggestion box hanged and My system stopped working. One of my friend also had the same problem. Is this a flutter problem or a problem in my system? Can it be fixed?

Comment: Same here! Yeah it only happens when I try to choose a color.